# How may I copy and paste to a file using VBA and Access 97?

Tags: ms-access, vba, append

I finally managed to connect VBA and a telnet-like terminal. 
Now I need to copy some screens to TXT files. 
Problem is I cannot use the append to file code:

```
Dim inputString As String = "This is a test string."
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText _
("C://testfile.txt", inputString, True)
```

It just doesn't work on VBA with Access 97 - everytime I drop the code it asks for a = or a ) and it just doesn't make any sense.

I know it's possible to send the values to a table and THEN export it as a TXT file, that's actually how I'm doing now:

```
rsttbl1!line01 = .copy(5, 38, 43)
rsttbl1!line02 = .copy(6, 38, 43)
rsttbl1!line03 = .copy(7, 38, 43)
rsttbl1!line04 = .copy(8, 38, 43)
rsttbl1!line05 = .copy(9, 38, 43)
```

But that's just too time consuming. 
I'm pretty sure that's possible, but I can't find any reference for it. 
And all I can find @microsoft.com just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is it me or are you just confusing VBA with VB .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused, you're quoting a .NET function and talking VBA for Access '97.

However, in .NET to append a file:

```
Imports System.IO 'Add to Imports section, can call it explicit if you'd like. System.IO.StreamWriter

    Dim writer As New StreamWriter("C:\test.txt", True)
    writer.WriteLine("Testing...")
    writer.Close()
```

As for a *Classic* VBA example:

```
Open "C:\test.txt" For Append As #1
    Print #1, "Testing..."
Close #1
```

Comment: HOLYCRAP! THAT'S IT!
I went tru all MS reference and I was looking at the WRONG reference?
MAN. THANKS OH SO MUCH!